# Format + Key Error - balance - Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am getting a format error for a form field that is not a date form field. I am not sure why it is giving me a form for something not related to the form field i am trying to fill...

Here is the exact error that is showing up:

```
ValidationError at /transfer/
["'0' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/transfer/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: ValidationError
Exception Value:    
["'0' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
Exception Location: C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py in to_python, line 1287
Python Executable:  C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\Desktop\\opentab\\opentab',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Here is the models file:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # server
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='first')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='last')
    dob = models.DateField(default='0')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=45, default='city')  # user
    state = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='state')
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)  # user
    privacy = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)  # user
    balance = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=9, default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  # server
```

here is the form.py:

```
class TransferForm(forms.ModelForm):
    acct_choices = (('Tabz', 'Tabz - Username'),
                    ('Wells Fargo', 'Wells Fargo - Username'))
    main = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices=acct_choices
    )
    transfer = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices=acct_choices
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Transfers
        fields = ['main', 'transfer', 'amount', 'memo']
```

here is the part that is processing the form and creating the new profile:

The error is in lines 9 - 14

```
if main == 'Tabz':
                    profiles = Profile.objects.all()
                    for profile in profiles:
                        if currentUser == profile.user:
                            currentProfile = profile
                            currentProfile.balance = currentProfile.balance - amount
                            currentProfile.save()
                        else:
                            new_balance = amount
                            new_profile =  Profile.objects.create(
                                user = currentUser,
                                balance = new_balance,
                            )
                    message = 'You have transfered ' + amount + ' from your Tabz account to main account'
                    new_activity = Acitivty.objects.create(
                        user = currentUser,
                        description = message,
                        status = 1,
                        category = 1,
                    )
                if transfer == 'Tabz':
                    profiles = Profile.objects.all()
                    for profile in profiles:
                        if currentUser == profile.user:
                            currentProfile = profile
                            currentProfile.balance = currentProfile.balance + amount
                            currentProfile.save()
                        else:
                            new_balance =  amount
                            new_profile =  Profile.objects.create(
                                user = currentUser,
                                balance = new_balance
                            )
                    message = 'You have transfered ' + amount + ' from your Tabz account to main account'
                    new_activity = Acitivty.objects.create(
                        user = currentUser,
                        description = message,
                        status = 1,
                        category = 1,
                    )
                return redirect('home_page')
```

Answer (score 3):

as you have taken a DateField and you have provided a defualt value of 0 thus the error is coming,

so change this line

```
dob = models.DateField(default='0')
```

to

```
dob = models.DateField(default='1900-01-01')
```

then `makemigrations` and `migrate`. and then try to submit your form

Comment: The default for a `models.DateField()` should be a `datetime.date` object, not a string.